# pyspark: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, databricks, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to read table from db(postgres) as spark data frame using databricks pyspark. Even though I gave all details correctly I am getting the below error. Does any body know the reason and solution for it?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
#from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
servername =XXXXXXX
port = 5432
Database = XXXXX
schema = XXXXX
table = XXXX
url = f"jdbc:postgresql://{servername}:{port}/{Database}"

db_properties = {
  'username': 'XXXXXX','password' : 'XXXXXXX',
    'driver': 'org.postgresql.Driver'}


df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=Database.table, properties=db_properties)
```

Error:- `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.`

And when I used ssh tunnel it says `no passwords' or public key available`

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(remote_bind_address=('psqlhost', 5432),local_bind_address=('localhost', 5432)):
   df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=Database.table, properties=db_properties)
```

Error:-

```
ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

Comment: I think passing "username" as db_properties is causing this issue as it not a valid property.  Could you please pass "user" instead and check if it works.  Please refer to - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html
Can you please check error details, specifically for "Caused by:" in the logs which could give you more information. (Example - 
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: {servername}.postgres.database.azure.com.